# Aptio Setup Utility - Cannot change boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, uefi, windows-installation

I am so sorry to ask this. I feel like a total idiot - Aptio Setup Utility has me licked. I just bought an ASUS X75V with Freedos, Version 2.15.1226.

The boot configuration has "Launch PXE OpROM disabled

The Boot Option Priorities are:

Boot Option #1
P2: Matshitsa DVD Ram UJ8E1
P0: HGST HTS5410109E680

Boot Option #2
P2: Matshitsa DVD Ram UJ8E1
P0: HGST HTS5410109E680

There is no "Fast Boot option to disable.

The problem is that I have a setup disk for Windows 7 burnt and ready to go, and when I finally got it to run from the disk, it gave me the following error message:

"Reboot and select proper boot device, or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key"

I have loaded the install file onto a USB port as well, but have no idea how to to create a path that will link to it. In other words, I am trapped here, and all of the instructions that I get work perfectly for other systems, with other options. After four hours of trying and being almost on the verge of hysteria that I wasted all this money on a doorstop that cannot be used, I must appeal to you to help me. Can someone please please please walk me through this? My eyes are beginning to cross from terms I do not understand: my DOS experience is rusty but passable, but this setup utility has me flummoxed.

I thank you in advance.

Jason

Comment: And... I found out what the problem was. Turns out that the DVD that I burnt on was corrupted. I reburnt and am currently installing like mad. I am so relieved.